# apache vhost redirect to https except a subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

I have a domain with SSL: https://www.example.de

Here ist my redirect, which runs very well.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.de$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://www.example.de/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} !^www.example.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://www.example.de/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But now, I have a subdomain http://click.example.de , which should be running over HTTP and not HTTPS.

At this moment the rules above are redirecting everything, also click.example.com to https://www.example.de .

How to except this subdomain, so it can remain on HTTP and resolve?

Thanks
Nik

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^click\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

`HTTPS_HOST` does not exist. You must use `HTTP_HOST`.

Comment: I do not understand why you do not redirect `www.example.de` to https

Comment: Well it should be redirected. Isn't It? I have seen this example in google and used it. How should be better done? Everything except click should be redirected to https://www.example.de

Comment: But this example is working only if there is one domain on the vhost. How should it work when there are more then one domain, for example: example.de and example.com

Comment: I change my code with that. I do not know if it works with vhost, but it's ok with htaccess.